# Speaking URL setup for news articles

Tags: url-rewriting, typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I'm setting up a Typo3 v9.5.15 site using the news extension for writing articles that should appear at `example.com/{$SLUG}` what I managed to archive is to display the articles on `example.com/p/{$SLUG}`.

Currently the setup is as follows:

- news articles are collected in a system folder `news-collection` and put into different categories.
- For each category there is a page listed in the main menu that contains a listing of the news articles for the given category. For the display of the article details from any category a single page is used.
- This details view for the articles is a page underneath root page in the page tree with the page ID 11. This page is not shown in the menu and has the URL path `/p/`

Reading the docs at [Routing in Typo3 9](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html#how-to-rewrite-urls-with-news-parameters) and [Advanced Routing Configuration (for Extensions)](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html) I came up with the following configuration for speaking URLs

```
  News:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 11
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
        routeFieldName: 'path_segment'
```

Now I want to get rid of the `/p/` part of the generated URL. As far as I understood the documentation the option

```
routeValuePrefix: '/'
```

should do the trick. However when doing so I get the error message by Typo3, that the page could not be found.

Could somebody please help me to solve the riddle? Thanks in advance!